# Symfony Login Session data

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I followed this Tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html and I am using the newest Version (4.2.x) but it seems the app is never setting the session value descriped here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#redirecting-to-the-last-accessed-page-with-targetpathtrait

Where and how do I set this? In the documentation it says it will be set automatically, but when I check the session in the debug console - there is nothing like this. The user/admin will now only be redirected to the set paths and never to the requested pages (e.g. somecontroller/action/id)

**security.yaml**

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

        logout:
            path:   app_logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
            secure: true
            name: REMEMBERUSER
        form_login:
            use_referer: true
```

**LoginFormAuthentificator.php**

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $path = 'adresses_index';
    } elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        $path = 'users_profile';
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($path));
}
```

Also I tried it by setting the providerkey hardcoded to **main** and set an hidden input field with _target_path in the login form. Both lead not to the user experience of opening a link which is restricted and after login redirecting the user to that path.

dumping

> $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)

returnes **null**.

Answer (score 0):

by default the variable _target_path is set only when the user accesses a private url (example: /my-account). If he is not connected, and wants to access this url, he will be returned to the login page, and the _target_path variable will be set. As mentioned above, the variable is defined only when a user wants to access a private url.

So, you have to tell symfony that you want to save too, no matter what the url is. The doc is here ( the example code is below )

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#redirecting-to-the-last-accessed-page-with-targetpathtrait

You can use the make:subscriber command to generate a default file, or create a file manually.

Then, just copy and paste the example code from the symfony doc into the generated file. Here is the code to put in the generate file.

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class RequestSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest() || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $this->saveTargetPath($this->session, 'main', $request->getUri());
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest']
        ];
    }
}
```

That's it, now all routes are redirected with a public / private URL.

NB: For private URLs now, when the user is not logged but types the url /dashboard for example in the browser, then redirects to the login form, the last URL saved in session will be the same page, so the login page. However, the user will have to be manually redirected according to his or her role. I leave an example below.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            if( in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $this->getUser()->getRoles() ) ):
                return $this->redirectToRoute('backend_home');
            elseif ( in_array('ROLE_VENDOR', $this->getUser()->getRoles() ) ):
                return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_account_vendor_dashboard');
            elseif ( in_array('ROLE_CUSTOMER', $this->getUser()->getRoles() ) ):
                return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_account_history');
            else:
                return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_home');
            endif;
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \Exception('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall');
    }
}
```